# Listen to javascript events from Dart

Tags: javascript, dart

Is there a way in Dart to listen for events from javascript libraries?

For example the jqrangeslider http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/ package emits a userValueChanged event when someone releases the slider.

Is it easy to listen for that event in Dart via the js/js.dart package?

Would love to see some examples of a listener in Dart that listens for events like this from a javascript library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [js package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js) you can deal with almost all js code. Here is the dart version of the following javascript code snippet :

```js
$("#slider").bind("valuesChanged", function(e, data){
  console.log("Will be executed");
});
```

In Dart :

```dart
js.scoped((){
  js.context.jQuery("#slider").bind("valuesChanged", new js.Callback.many((e, data) {
    print("Will be executed");
  }));
});
```

Note that I use `jQuery` instead of `$` because you would have issue with *dart2js* otherwise (see [issue 2265](http://dartbug.com/2265)).

Basically, when you use callback functions in JS, you have to use `js.Callback.many` or `js.Callback.once` to wrap your callback. See [Managing callback lifetimes](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/js-dart-interop/#managing-callback-lifetimes) for more details.

Comment: When I do what you have suggested using **jQuery** I get this error: **The method 'jQuery' is not defined for the class 'Proxy'**. Any suggestions? ps: same error if I use $ :-(

Comment: It's only a warning that will disappear in the next days. However the code should work.

Comment: Code isn't working. I will post as an answer it would be fantastic if you can point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Don't you forget to load jquery.js ?

Comment: I do , here is the details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18639922/using-jqrangeslider-with-dart-js-interop-does-not-work

Comment: @AlexandreArdhuin. There is no scoped(), bind() or Callback.many() in the js package now. Were they removed? And what to use instead? Thanks.