# Using jqrangeslider with dart js-interop does not work

Tags: jquery-ui, dart, dart-webui, dart-js-interop

I am trying to use the jqrangeslider ( http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/index.html ) in my web_ui app and it is not working.

In my application main root dart file I have:

```
void main() {

js.scoped((){
  js.context.jQuery("#slider").bind("valuesChanged", new js.Callback.many((e, data) {
    fromRange = data.values.min;
    toRange = data.values.max;
  }));
});
```

main root html file I have:

```
  <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jQRangeSlider-min.js"></script>
  <script src="../packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  <script src="../packages/browser/interop.js"></script>
```

In the custom components html file I have:

```
<div id="slider"></div>

<script>
    $("#slider").rangeSlider();
  </script>
```

The slider simply does not appear at all.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I just maid a quick test with `js.context.jQuery('*').hide();` and this works as expected. Isn't there some errors in the js console or in the Editor at runtime ?

Comment: No errors at all , slider simply does not appear :-(

Comment: Actually there is a css error but I didn't think it was relevant: Invalid CSS property value: grab  (iThing.css)

Comment: If I understand correctly you load the slider from Js ? If true your problem doesn't look to be related to js-interop.

Comment: as first time using js-interop not sure what I am doing tell you the truth. How should I be loading the slider in my custom component? Thanks.

Comment: I don't really know how Js script are handled by web_ui. Try to call `js.context.jQuery('#slider').rangeSlider()` in the main of your component.dart file.

Comment: Bit I am confused about is whether we I can do this inside the custom component or does it have to be done in main? Maybe problem is the component is not loaded yet for #slider query to be found. What do you think ?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know well how web_ui works.