# Listen to JS object's events from Dart

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

I need to listen to `ready` events from a JS object ([wavesurfer.js](http://wavesurfer.fm/)). I initialize the object with:

```dart
var wavesurfer = context['WaveSurfer'];
```

And call its `init` function with:

```dart
wavesurfer.callMethod('init', [mapOptions]);
```

But I'm unable to listen on ready events like in this JS code:

```js
wavesurfer.on('ready', function () {
   wavesurfer.play();
});
```

I found solutions for similar problems like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15842633/listen-to-javascript-events-from-dart) but all are using functions that appear deprecated such as `js package`'s scoped() and Callback.many().

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Could please send me some code snippets of how you implemented wavesurfer-js in Dart, cause I also wanted to display that UI in Flutter Web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With dart:js :

```dart
wavesurfer.callMethod('on', ['ready', () {
  wavesurfer.callMethod('play');
}]);
```

Comment: Awesome. This is almost identical to the JS code. I still have this problem though. `context['WaveSurfer.Timeline'];` should return a JS object after `wavesurfer` is `ready` like the JS equivalent `Object.create(WaveSurfer.Timeline);`. But, it returns `null`. I have no idea why. I tested the JS equivalent on the same webpage and it works.

Comment: Does the problem have to do with the way the object is instantiated with the dot in the middle?

Comment: You have to use `context['WaveSurfer']['Timeline']` to get the equivalent of `WaveSurfer.Timeline`.

Comment: Alexandre. You're awesome. Thank you so much for your help.